# Failed to Create Meshlab Visual Studio 2013 Project

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qmake, meshlab

I'm trying to open [meshlab](https://github.com/starseeker/meshlab) project in visual studio 2013. I did install [Cmake](https://cmake.org/download/) and Qt 5.3.0 on my windows 10 and then run this command :

```
cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 12 Win64"
```

and after running that :

```
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 18.0.31101.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 18.0.31101.0
-- Check for working C compiler using: Visual Studio 12 2013 Win64
-- Check for working C compiler using: Visual Studio 12 2013 Win64 -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler using: Visual Studio 12 2013 Win64
-- Check for working CXX compiler using: Visual Studio 12 2013 Win64 -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
*** Configuring MeshLab Version 1.3.2 ****
-- Found OpenGL: opengl32
-- Looking for include file dlfcn.h
-- Looking for include file dlfcn.h - not found
-- Looking for include file inttypes.h
-- Looking for include file inttypes.h - found
-- Looking for include file memory.h
-- Looking for include file memory.h - found
-- Looking for include file stdint.h
-- Looking for include file stdint.h - found
-- Looking for include file stdlib.h
-- Looking for include file stdlib.h - found
-- Looking for include file strings.h
-- Looking for include file strings.h - not found
-- Looking for include file string.h
-- Looking for include file string.h - found
-- Looking for include file sys/stat.h
-- Looking for include file sys/stat.h - found
-- Looking for include file sys/types.h
-- Looking for include file sys/types.h - found
-- Looking for include file unistd.h
-- Looking for include file unistd.h - not found
-- Looking for cos in m
-- Looking for cos in m - not found
-- lmdemo will be linked against levmar;lapack;blas;f2c
CMake Error at E:/MyWorkSpace/Meshinator/Qt/Qt5.3.0/5.3/msvc2013_64_opengl/lib/cmake/Qt5Gui/Qt5GuiConfigExtras.cmake:14 (message):
  Failed to find "glu32" in "" with CMAKE_CXX_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURE "".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  E:/MyWorkSpace/Meshinator/Qt/Qt5.3.0/5.3/msvc2013_64_opengl/lib/cmake/Qt5Gui/Qt5GuiConfigExtras.cmake:50 (_qt5gui_find_extra_libs)
  E:/MyWorkSpace/Meshinator/Qt/Qt5.3.0/5.3/msvc2013_64_opengl/lib/cmake/Qt5Gui/Qt5GuiConfig.cmake:152 (include)
  E:/MyWorkSpace/Meshinator/Qt/Qt5.3.0/5.3/msvc2013_64_opengl/lib/cmake/Qt5Widgets/Qt5WidgetsConfig.cmake:94 (find_package)
  src/other/structuresynth/CMakeLists.txt:17 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "E:/MyWorkSpace/Meshinator/meshlab-master/_build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "E:/MyWorkSpace/Meshinator/meshlab-master/_build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

As you see I get this error from cmak :

```
CMake Error at E:/MyWorkSpace/Meshinator/Qt/Qt5.3.0/5.3/msvc2013_64_opengl/lib/cmake/Qt5Gui/Qt5GuiConfigExtras.cmake:14 (message):
      Failed to find "glu32" in "" with CMAKE_CXX_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURE "".
```

I did google that error and find this answer :

> *To solve the problem use this line :  set (CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH “C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Lib\win8\um\x64”)*

Now I don't know where I can add this line? please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add it to the CMakeList.txt that apperantly recides on the higher level directory from where you try to run CMake.

Comment: Thanks Jovasa! I add this line to CMakeList.txt file but that error is not change. Is my path format wrong?

Comment: Does this path “C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Lib\win8\um\x64” exist to begin with?

Comment: Yes, it's exist! I mean C:\\ or C:/ or C://